# PowerShell: running commands in sequence

Tags: azure, powershell, sequential

I am rather new to PowerShell, still getting my head around but at the moment, I am trying to create a script in PS Ise that starts with: Connect-AzureAD, followed by Get-AzureUserAD but whatever I have tried the script won't keep running after the first line:Connect to AzureAD.
If somebody can explain me what I am doing wrong.

Thank You

REF:
1-Connect-AzureAD
2-Get-AzureADUser - Searchstring......

Tried to use the ; between each command and && with no success
[Connect-AzureAD PS ISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfN5U.png)

Comment: How exactly are you executing the code from ISE? F5? F8? Copy-paste into the prompt?

Comment: I am using PS ISE, the idea would be to run all commands using the same .PS1. But right now the script stops after connecting to Azure

Comment: Please answer the question: _how_ are you executing it. What exact steps do you take to run the commands?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of PS ISE, from there I try run the script, but it will only run the connect-azureAD, asking for my credentials and it stops there. Instead it should give me the membership of the user once connected to AzureAD

Comment: Again: _how_ do you "try to run the script"? Do you click the green play-button on top? Or the one next to it? Does ISE show you any output/errors when you do?

Comment: I ran the script by pressing the green button(F5) and did try to use the one next(F8). I get no errors when the script runs the first line, there is the pop up message where I need to add my admin account mailbox, then it simply stops after my credentials have been verified

Comment: It might be that you've configured errors to be suppressed, and that the second command fails because it doesn't exist (you probably want `Get-AzureADUser` rather than `Get-AzureUserAD`) - try adding `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` on the first line, execute the script again, and then look at the console below the editor - does it show an error?

Comment: Do you have AzureAD module installed on your computer? Try before `Install-Module -Name AzureAD`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Get-AzureUserAD but whatever I have tried the script won't keep running after the first line:Connect to AzureAD:

As given by @Mathias R. Jessen, there is no command called `Get-AzureUserAD` in Azure PowerShell commands.

Instead, you need to give [`Get-AzureADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) command to list out the users as shown below.

Once it is done, you can also execute [`Get-AzureADUserMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadusermembership?view=azureadps-2.0) to retrieve the user memberships.

*Note:* Make sure that the Azure AD module is installed successfully without any conflicts.
`Install-Module -Name AzureAD`

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "xxxx"
Get-AzureADUserMembership  -ObjectId "xxx"
```

[image]

If you are trying to get the AD user by searching it with a string, use below format.

`Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "jahnavi"`

[image]